# str_getcsv returns Incomplete Column on Tab-delimited CSV

Tags: php, arrays, csv

Here's my tab-delimited CSV (I made it space here instead of tab by the way):

```
header1 header2 header3 header4
value1  value2  value3
value2  value2
```

If I use this function, it returns the CSV as an array but incomplete:

```
$content = file($file, FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$rows = array_map('str_getcsv', $content, array_fill(0, count($content), "\t"));
```

This doesn't work either:

```
if(file_exists($file)){
    $rows = array_map(function($v){
        return str_getcsv($v, "\t");
    }, file($file, FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES));
}
```

Output:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
            [0] => header1
            [1] => header2
            [2] => header3
            [3] => header4
        )
    [1] => Array(
            [0] => value1
            [1] => value2
            [2] => value3
        )
    [2] => Array(
            [0] => value1
            [1] => value2
        )
)
```

It seems that it treats the empty tab as one so the values would have incomplete array as opposed to the header.

Expected:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
            [0] => header1
            [1] => header2
            [2] => header3
            [3] => header4
        )
    [1] => Array(
            [0] => value1
            [1] => value2
            [2] => value3 
            [3] =>
        )
    [2] => Array(
            [0] => value1
            [1] => value2
            [2] => 
            [3] => 
        )
)
```

Comment: Yeah I realized I have posted a space-delimited CSV but in essence, if it's tab, the output would be the same as above where the values don't  have equal number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

if u want output like:

Array(
            [0] => header1
            [1 ] => header2
            [2] => header3
            [3] => header4
            [4] => value1
            [5] => value2
            ...
        )

just change your data csv, but if you dont want to change it.
u can try to use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function